# Split text into sentences with Stanford NLP containing periods in text

Tags: java, kotlin, stanford-nlp

I am trying to split a complex sentence with location text that contains multiple periods in "string numbers"

For example:

```
val text = "First sentence 24-18.07N. Next sentence."
val document = Document(text)
val sentences = document.sentences()
```

In this case I only get one sentence.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could append a space to the text and split it by ". ".

Comment: @ValerijDobler I suppose I could, wondering why stanford NLP would not pick something like this up.